# Batch convert png to jpg and output images to new folder imagemagick

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, imagemagick

```
mogrify  -flatten -quality 100  *.jpg -format  jpg *.png
```

I need output images to new folder, so what I need to do ?

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -q:v 3 -quality 100
```

> "newfiles\%%~na.jpg" pause

and what different between `-q:v3`(ffmpeg) and without `-q:v`(imagemagick) ?

THANK

Comment: Does this command, which could be put into a batch script, give you the result you want. If so, what is the problem?

Comment: No, if work fine...but i just need output to new folder, not the same as source folder. Because, if it same as source folder..i will need sorting type of files... then copy converted files to new folder i was created before.

Old command : 3 Step 
New command (Mark Setchell) : It reduce to 2, time saving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there...

```
mkdir OutputDir
mogrify -path OutputDir -format jpg -flatten -quality 100 *.png
```

If you want to restrict the output size to, say 600kb, you can add the following into the command line:

```
-define jpeg:extent=600kb
```

I cannot seem to make that work if I use it with `mogrify`, nor does it seem to work if I use it with `convert` and the input file is `PNG` format. I have no idea why, as I am sure it used to work. Anyway, that means you would need to do this to reduce the quality just enough to get the size you want:

```
convert -define jpeg:extent=600kb input.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: But you can answer my 2nd question ? plz

I use that ffmpeg command to lower size of images with -q:v (color,pixel same as source when you view it with 100% zoom...you need zoom 200-300% to recognize the difference between original and converted. So, imagemagick have this option (-q:v) ?

thank

Comment: Can you explain what it means in English? I read the manpage for `ffmpeg` and it talks about setting `VBR` for a channel, yet still images don't have bitrates as far as I know, so I find it quite incomprehensible. What do you want ImageMagick to do? Limit the size of the output file? Decrease the colour quantisation?

Comment: english is not my primary language, hard to express, so i take a screenshot from two files converted by ffmpeg and imagemagick
here's link : http://imgur.com/a/lGD3w
. as you can see.. ffmpeg 623KB, once i zoom 400% , i can see the noise. So imagemagick have this option ? I dont need to zoom 3-400% to see a difference.

THANK

Comment: It was the English in the `Help` pages for `ffmpeg` that I cannot understand! Do you want ImageMagick to reduce noise? Or to make the file smaller? Or something else?

Comment: I have added some information on this - I hope that helps.

Comment: Here's my new command :

mkdir OutputDir

mogrify -path OutputDir -format jpg -flatten -quality 86 png:compression-level=9    *.*

quality 86 imagemagick ~ quality 100 -q:v 3 ffmpeg