Large image resize to small thumbnail
I have large JPEG images of around 2000 x 1500 (a few Megabytes in size).
I wish to resize them for display to 200 x 150 (ideally 10KB or so) in a phone app.
I'd like to know what would be the best steps given I want a reasonably small size and as good a quality (given the maximum size).
Some options:

First reduce dimensions to exactly 200x150 and then if size is not 10KB yet, to change the quality of JPG until I get the correct size. Is it a good practice to create the exact thumbnail size I need?

OR, reduce dimensions to a slightly larger thumbnail than required (eg. 400 x 300, or 300 x 225 ETC) - is there a "best practice" to get a photo size larger than the one you are displaying? Then change the quality of JPG until size is obtained.

Resize to much larger than 200x150. Just change quality of JPG until it hits 10Kb or less.


A related question: for JPEG, once I reduce the dimensions (pixels size), I wish to adjust the quality of the JPG output until a target size is obtained. Can this only be done by trial and error? Currently, I try a higher % first then keep lowering it until the desired size is reached, but it's not ideal as it uses quite a fair bit of CPU cycles.
Is there an approximate formulae that will tell me to get from 50KB to 10KB, I need to drop from 100% JPG quality to 79%, for example.
Example: after I reduce the dimensions, a 4MB photo becomes 0.5MB. Is there a formula by which each % of a reduction in JPG quality will result in how many % of the JPG size, so that I can get as close to 10KB without too much trial and error?

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26632460/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33184499/2836621

Basically, this needs trial & error. There can't be a formula, because how much file size reduction you can achieve by lowering the quality, depends less on input file size, and much more on the actual image content.

Thank you for the reply. Looks like a "binary" method is the way to go?
